# os specific pre_task in ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to run a set of raw commands (to install python) if a given
operating system on the target host is OpenBSD

I have to run these checks as pre_tasks (because to run anything as a task Python must already be present on the target system)

What I do not understand is, whether any OS characteristics variables are available in pre_task stage (like ansible_os_family)

```
- name: Check for Python 
      raw: test -e /usr/bin/python
      changed_when: false
      failed_when: false
      register: check_python


- name: Install Python on OpenBSD
      # raw: test -e /usr/bin/apt && (apt -y update && apt install -y python-minimal) || (yum -y install python libselinux-python)
      raw: pkg_add -r python%3  
      when: check_python.rc != 0
      when: ansible_os_family == "OpenBSD" # <-- problem here
```

I seem to get a problem when trying to use ansible_os_family

Is there a way to enable the pre_tasks without me writing my own os family checks?

PS. I used the above python installation code, following recommendation here:
[1] https://relativkreativ.at/articles/how-to-install-python-with-ansible

Comment: `because to run anything as a task Python must already be present on the target system` can you please explain why is that ? `raw` can be used as a task, pre_task, or even post_task. What is true is that you will not be able to `gather_facts` until python is installed, hence you won't be able to detect the OS easillly since the related variables (e.g. `ansible_os_family`, ....) won't be available.

Comment: @Zeitounator , you are right, I should have been more precise: without Python on the target host, we cannot run tasks that depend on other tasks that require python.  But in the context of my problem, I think what I wrote makes sense: I need to install python on target host, but I need to 'detect', somehow, that the target host is OpenBSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: *"Is there a way to enable the pre_tasks without me writing my own os family checks?"*

A: No. It is not. Python is needed to collect the [facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html#setup-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts).

---

See the verbose output. For example the output of connecting FreeBSD 12 remote host from the Ubuntu controller

```sh
shell> ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6
...
python version = 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) [GCC 9.3.0]

shell> ansible test_01 -m setup -vvv
```

> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
>    SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="admin"' -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o ControlPath=/export/home/admin.config/.ansible/cp/5a3ab05cf7 test_01 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/local/bin/python3.7 && sleep 0'"'"''

Without Python installed the module will crash

> (127, b'', b'/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python: not found\n')
>    Failed to connect to the host via ssh: /bin/sh: /usr/bin/python: not found
>   [WARNING]: No python interpreters found for host test_01 (tried ['/usr/bin/python',
>   'python3.7', 'python3.6', 'python3.5', 'python2.7', 'python2.6', '/usr/libexec/platform-
>   python', '/usr/bin/python3', 'python'])
>   test_01 | FAILED! => {
>       "ansible_facts": {
>           "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
>       },
>       "changed": false,
>       "module_stderr": "/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python: not found\n",
>       "module_stdout": "",
>       "msg": "The module failed to execute correctly, you probably need to set the interpreter.\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
>       "rc": 127
>   }

Comment: thank you. But when I run: ansible -m setup  myOpenBSD_host_without_python  --vault-id @prompt --ask-pass  . I get an output with variables (including correct ansible_os_family).  It is just that I cannot seem to use it in pre_task (and my pre_tasks is a directory under a specific role )

Comment: If you run that command and get a result, a version (whatever) of python has been found on your host. Else you would get an error. You can check which executable has been used on the target in `ansible_python.executable` in the result. To use those vars (in any task) your play must not shut off facts gathering (i.e. not declare `gather_facts: false` which is true by default). If you gather facts on hosts without python, your playbook will fail.

Comment: Ok thank you. My analysis seems to be wrong then. Will take it that python must be installed to detect the os version via ansible. Thank you Vladimir for your follow up, and your work on the ansible's nginx role (I use it extensively).

Answer (score 3):

Following your latest comments, as said earlier by @Vladimir and myself, you will not be able to use ansible's facts variables to detect the OS on hosts without python since it is impossible to gather facts (i.e. play the `setup` module). You need to do that job on your own for this first step.

I don't have a BSD system I can access. So the below is totally untested for your platform. But I believe it should work, or at least put you on track. Check the content of `/etc/os-release` on your system to adapt the regex if needed. The one I wrote gave a correct result on Ubuntu, Debian, Centos, RHEL and on RedHat UBI and Alpine docker images.

```yaml
---
- name: Fix hosts with no python at all
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Perform a dirty OS detection if python is not installed
      raw: |-
        if which python > /dev/null || which python3 > /dev/null; then
          echo installed
        else
          sed -n "s/^NAME=\"\(.*\)\"/\\1/p" /etc/os-release
        fi
      changed_when: false
      register: dirty_detect

    - name: Print message when already installed
      debug:
        msg: Host {{ inventory_hostname }} already has python. Next will skip.
      when: dirty_detect.stdout_lines[0] == 'installed'

    - name: Install python on openbsd if needed
      raw: |-
        pkg_add -r python%3
      become: true
      when: dirty_detect.stdout_lines[0] == 'OpenBSD'

    - name: Install python on Ubuntu if needed
      raw: |-
        apt install -y python3
      become: true
      when: dirty_detect.stdout_lines[0] == 'Ubuntu'

- name: Back to normal life with ansible
  hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: Now we gathered facts and we can use all facts vars
      debug:
        msg: Host {{ inventory_hostname }} is running {{ ansible_os_familly }}

    - name: We might have left hosts with python 2.7 only above, make sure python3 is installed
      package:
        name: python3
      become: true
```

Comment: thank you.  You listed above as tasks, but shouldn't those be 'pre_task' , so that it gets executed before anything else for that role?

Comment: There where no roles in your example nor mine so it was not needed. And I wanted to make clear that the problem does not depend on pre/post/normal tasks. Note also that I made 2 plays sot that the second one can gather facts automatically. I would put my roles on the second play once I'm sure all my hosts are ready to run ansible normally.